# How to correctly connect SQLite Database with a ListFragment?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-listfragment

I am  very new with Fragments and trying to learn how to work with them. I do programming for hobby, so please don't be to harsh... ;)

So I set up an app with slideable tabs with the Eclipse assistant. At this point two tabs are connected with normal Fragments, which works. But I want a third tab which shows the content of a database.

My problem is, how do I connect ListFragment and Database correctly? All I got is a ProgressCircle running non-stop.

I've already got some experience with ListActivitys and SQLiteDatabases on which i orientated myself. So I suppose my database-code is okay, as I get no errors. I believe that my error is in the ListFragment-class but I have no idea what to do as Eclipse does not show any errors... Also I worked with Databases when Android 3 was ongoing, so I don't want to exlude that something may has changed...

So this is the code of my ListFragment:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class GefilterteListe extends ListFragment {

    public static final String TAG = GefilterteListe.class.getSimpleName();

    private FilterDatenbankHandler dbHandler;
    private Cursor dbCursor;
    private LehrerDatenbankAdapter dbAdapter;
    private Context mContext;

    public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Log.i(TAG, "GefilterteListe onCreate");
        View returnView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.plan, container, false);
        mContext = getActivity();
        dbHandler = new FilterDatenbankHandler(mContext);
        dbCursor = dbHandler.query();
        ((Activity) mContext).startManagingCursor(dbCursor);
        dbAdapter = new LehrerDatenbankAdapter(mContext, dbCursor);
        setListAdapter(dbAdapter);

        return returnView;
    }

}
```

And this is the plan.xml with which I want to show the data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Krzl"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Tag"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Datum"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Stunde: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="Stunde"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Merkmal: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Merkmal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:text="Info: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView8"
        android:text="Info"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

If you need the code of the Adapter or/and Handler, please tell me. Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**
Below this sentence I added the handler and adapter.
Handler:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class FilterDatenbankHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String TAG = FilterDatenbankHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    //Name und Version der Datenbank
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Lehrer.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //Name und Attribute der Tabelle "vertretungsplan"
    private static final String _ID = "_id";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Lehrerdatenbank";
    private static final String KUERZEL = "kürzel";
    private static final String WOCHENTAG = "tag";
    private static final String DATUM = "datum";
    private static final String STUNDE = "stunde";
    private static final String MERKMAL = "merkmal";
    private static final String INFO = "info";

    //Tabelle "vertretungsplan11" anlegen
    private static final String TABLE_CREATE = " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KUERZEL + " STRING, " + WOCHENTAG + " STRING, " + DATUM + " STRING, " + STUNDE + " STUNDE, " + MERKMAL
            + " STRING, " + INFO + " STRING ); ";

    //Tabelle "test" löschen
    private static final String TABLE_DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

    FilterDatenbankHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
//      Log.i(TAG, "DatenbankHandler wurde initiiert.");
    }   


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        Log.i(TAG, "FilterDatenbankHandler: " + db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgraden der Datenbank von Version " + oldVersion + " zu Version " + newVersion + "; alle Daten werden gelöscht");
        db.execSQL(TABLE_DROP);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void redoTbl(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(TABLE_DROP);
        Log.i(TAG, "Lehrer-Tabelle gelöscht");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insert(String kuerzel, String tag, String datum, String stunde, String merkmal, String info){
        long rowId = -1;
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KUERZEL, kuerzel);
            values.put(WOCHENTAG, tag);
            values.put(DATUM, datum);
            values.put(STUNDE, stunde);
            values.put(MERKMAL, merkmal);
            values.put(INFO, info);
            rowId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            Log.i(TAG, "insert: " + kuerzel + ", " + tag + ", " + datum + ", " + stunde + ", " + merkmal + ", " + info); //I get this Log, so i suppose it does work.
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "insert()", e);
        } finally {
            Log.i(TAG, "insert(): rowId=" + rowId);
        }
    }

    public Cursor query() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        return db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null,
                null, null, _ID +  " ASC" );
    }

}
```

Adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LehrerDatenbankAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

    private LayoutInflater inflator;
    private int s;
    String TAG = "LehrerDatenbankAdapter";

    public LehrerDatenbankAdapter(Context context, Cursor c){
        super(context, c);
        inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        s = c.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView textview1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);//Kürzel
        TextView textview2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);//tag
        TextView textview3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);//datum
        TextView textview4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView5);//Stunde
        TextView textview5 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView7);//Merkmal
        TextView textview6 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView9);//Info

        textview1.setText(cursor.getString(1));
        textview2.setText(cursor.getString(2));
        textview3.setText(cursor.getString(3));
        textview4.setText(cursor.getString(4));
        textview5.setText(cursor.getString(5));
        textview6.setText(cursor.getString(6));

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context arg0, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflator.inflate(R.layout.plan, null);
    }

}
```

While I was editing this post, I got the idea, that I might have an import wrong, but i couldn't find out, if one of these is wrong as this is new to me, too.
And I hope I didn't simply forget something, that would be embarrassing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! I simply had to write a onCreate method and had to insert my code there and not in the onCreateView method...

Answer (score 0):

Providing the dbAdapter and dbHandler code will help, as it will show if you're actually opening and how you're querying your database.  You might want to look at the SimpleCursorAdaptor.  Also, if you're using 4.x, you might want to get into Cursorloader and LoaderManager as combined, they provide all the work of opening and closing the database and all the threading stuff (check this http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html ), but I suggest you make sure your cursor and database queries are fully functional and working before switching to loaders.  I had a fully functional app without loaders but ran into some UI performance problems with listview scrolling.  Switching to loaders solved it all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I added the adapter and handler.

Comment: I already once stumbled across the Loadermanager but underestimated its possibilitys and anyway I will have to learn how to use it. 
Same with the SimpleCursorAdapter...

Sorry for the doublepost, I edited the comment too slow...